# Convert java.util.Set attributes with Commons BeanUtils

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a problem converting the following request URL:

```
entity.name=Test&entity.window[0].size=1&entity.windows[1].size=2
```

to the following JavaBean:

```
public class House {
    private String nome;

    private Set<Window> windows;

    // ... getters and setters ...
}

public class Window {
    private int size;

    // ... getters and setters ...
}
```

I get this error when I use `BeanUtils.populate`:

**Property 'windows' is not indexed on bean class 'class House'**

I think this problem occurs because Sets don’t have a known order to follow. So I can’t map values with indices like [0]...[1]...[2]. For my purpose, for converting request params to `java.util.Set` attributes, can I continue using `BeanUtils` with some adjustments or do I have to pick another library (which one)?

Comment: What about using a `List` instead? As you correctly state, sets do not maintain any order of their elements.

Comment: Because I can't edit the source code, it must be a Set

Comment: Well, in that case, an expression like `windows[0]` is pretty meaningless. Of course you could use the iterator's order, but this is not guaranteed to be consistent. Just inserting another element or removing one can change the iterator's order. An option would be to write an adapter for `House` that offers the same interface as `House` and additionally provides [JavaBean indexed property getters/setters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) for the windows property

Comment: I will do that, but a way to solve this is convert the `Window` objects first, and just after add to the Set, therefore `Equals and Hashcode` will be used to comparison.